# XNA View Matrix Issues

Tags: c#, matrix, xna

I've been working on something that loads the geometry of a game and follows the players position and view but I've ran into a problem:  I can't rotate the view without all the axis being messed up.

Here's a screenshot of the program with a pitch and yaw of 0 (just like the game's client):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXhIr.jpg

Here's my view matrix code:

```
public void UpdateViewMatrix()
{
        Vector3 pos = Position;
        pos.X *= -1;
        pos.Y *= -1;
        pos.Z *= -1;

        this.ViewMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(1) * Matrix.CreateLookAt(Vector3.Zero, new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 1)) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(pos) * Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(-MathHelper.PiOver2, -MathHelper.PiOver2, MathHelper.Pi);

        this.Frustum.Matrix = (this.ViewMatrix * this.ProjectionMatrix);
        if (this.CameraUpdated != null) this.CameraUpdated(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

I'm unsure why I have to flip all the coordinates as well before I update the view matrix.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure why it happens, but it must be related to mixing matrices which describe a view with ones which describe a world. If you want to solve it, then instead of multiplying the rotation matrix with the view use it to transform the look at target vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm unsure why I have to flip all the coordinates as well before I
>   update the view matrix

You probably don't.

In an Xna first person shooter, an easy way to handle the camera's view matrix to follow a character is to create a copy of that character's world matrix, offset it behind and slightly above, then invert it. That way, all the rotation and position manipulation that is done for the player does not have to be duplicated for the camera. This is a simple example of this:

```
//player moved and rotated and player's world matrix is determined

Matrix cameraWorld = playerWorld;
cameraWorld.Translation += (cameraWorld.Backward * followingDistance) +
                           (cameraWorld.Up * verticalOffset);
ViewMatrix = Matrix.Invert(cameraWorld);
```

Now the camera view matrix is orientated identically as the player and will stick to him like glue.

Comment: Would the playerWorld matrix be a transformation matrix of the player's Vector3 position?

Comment: It is a combination of both the rotation and position of the player. It is then same matrix you set the effect.World to when rendering the player.

Comment: This ended up kinda helping me - I found out I was accidentally using my original viewmatrix (the first time I updated it) as my world matrix when rendering the map's vertices.